# How to assign the values of select option from json parsed array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, select

I have this array that was returned by json.

```
{1:Android, 2:IOS, 3:Business Management Systems, 4:Database, 5:Codes/Scripts, 6:Others}
```

or

```
1: "Android"
2: "IOS"
3: "Business Management Systems"
4: "Database"
5: "Codes/Scripts"
6: "Others"
```

This array is saved on a variable `data`. And my current code of `ajax` is:

```
$.post('fetchSubCategory',{val:val},function(data){
            var subCategory = $.map(data, function(el){
                return el;
            });
             $.each(subCategory, function(key, value) {   
                 $('#subCategory')
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append($('<option>', { value : key })
                    .text(value)); 
            });
      });
```

But it returns this `[object Object]`. I want this array to populate my `select` element that the values are those ids and the texts are those names. Something to be like this:

```
<select class="form-control square" id="subCategory" name="Category">
    <option value="1">Android</option>
    <option value="2">IOS</option>
    <option value="3">Business Management Systems</option>
    <option value="4">Database</option>
    <option value="5">Codes/Scripts</option>
    <option value="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

How could I achieve this on `Javascript` or `jquery`.

Comment: I edited my question sir with my current code.

Comment: Does the `select` element exist or does it have to be created together with it's child `option` elements?

Comment: it exist sir with an id of `subCategory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Concept Verification**](http://jsfiddle.net/25td5uq3)

The following will append `option` element to an existing `#subCategory` select element:

```
$.post('fetchSubCategory',{val:val},function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
        $('#subCategory').append(
            $('<option/>').val( key ).text( value )
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: same thing happened sir. still returns `[object Object]` and not the actual array.

Comment: Please print out the result of `console.log( data )`.

Comment: this is the log of the `data` `0: {7:Graphic Design, 8:Portraits, 9:Photographs, 10:Compositions, 11:Paintings, 12:3D Modeling/Design, 13:Others}`

Comment: What about `console.log( data[0].7 )` or `console.log( data[0]['7'] )`?

Comment: I spotted the glitch sir. Not on `ajax` side but on my `php`. I have returned the json value like this `return json([$array]);` that's why it logs with `0:` before the real array. So I removed that `[]` to look like this `return json($array);` then I used this code and it works. Thank you.